# Show suggested edits in Markdown diff mode when something inside a spoiler is changed

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, spoilers

I just encountered [this suggested edit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/530730) which states

> added some periods; rewording

It opens in the side-by-side view, which only shows the change in the non-spoiler part of the edit:

[image]

It would be better to show this in the Markdown view, where the changes are much more obvious:

[image]

When only the spoiler text is changed, like in [this edit 'for science'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/83040), no changes are visible *at all*.